# Kotlin aggregate consecutive list elements

Tags: kotlin

I'd like to sum up consecutive numbers in a Kotlin list.
If the list has a 0 then it should start summing up the numbers after 0. The result would be a list of sums. Basically sum up until the first 0 then until the next 0 and so forth.
For example:

```
    val arr = arrayOf(1, 2, 0, 2, 1, 3, 0, 4)
    // list of sums =  [3,        6,       4]
```

At the moment I got it working with `fold`:

```
    val sums: List<Int> = arr.fold(listOf(0)) { sums: List<Int>, n: Int ->
        if (n == 0)
            sums + n
        else
            sums.dropLast(1) + (sums.last() + n)
    }
```

but I wonder if there is a simpler or more efficient way of doing this.

Answer (score 1):

I would personally have written it this way:

```kotlin
val sums = mutableListOf(0).also { acc ->
    arr.forEach { if (it == 0) acc.add(0) else acc[acc.lastIndex] += it }
  }
```

Using a mutable list, you avoid having to do any drop / concatenation. The code is also easier to follow.

You can still convert it to an immutable list using `.toList()` if you need to.